# SQL - How to UNION one column and FULL JOIN another column?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

1. Table *Prices* - primary key `ID`, `price`
2. Table *DiscountPrices* - primary key `ID`, `discountPrice`

**Prices**

```
ID | price  
1  | 15  
2  | 29  
3  | 21
```

**DiscountPrices**

```
ID | discountPrices  
1  | 12  
3  | 18   
4  | 22
```

I  need to get:

```
ID | price | discountPrice  
1  |  15   | 12    
2  |  29   | NULL  
3  |  21   | 18  
4  |  NULL | 22
```

1.To get total ID list I can use:

```
SELECT ID FROM Prices
UNION
SELECT ID FROM DiscountPrices
```

2.To get price, discountPrice I can use:

```
SELECT price, discountPrice 
FROM Prices FULL JOIN DiscountPrices 
ON Prices.ID = DiscountPrices.ID
```

In this point I've stopped. Could you give me some hints? :)

Comment: Use an Outer join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: Change to `full outer join` instead of `full join` and you should get what you need (assuming SQL server)

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I am just learning SQL without considering specific implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `FULL JOIN` to `FULL OUTER JOIN` will solve your problem :

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.ID, dp.id) AS ID, p.price, dp.discountPrice 
FROM Prices p FULL OUTER JOIN 
     DiscountPrices  dp
     ON p.ID = dp.ID;
```

Only `JOIN` will considered as `INNER JOIN`, but you need `OUTER JOIN`.